# Using Data Provider and TextNG XML together

Tags: java, xml, selenium-webdriver, ioexception, testng-dataprovider

I can't figure out how to integrate `TestNG XML` with Data Providers from an Excel Sheet.

I have confirmed my code Data Provider syntax is correct as my test runs successfully when I run it from the Test Level (See Below)

[image: Excel DataProvider screen shot]

However, when I try to implement the Data Provider Using the `TestNG XML` Configuration (I am trying to run usernames and passwords against multiple browsers) I am getting a Java IOException and (as those can be pretty vague) I am not sure how to proceed.

Please see the screenshots included below of the same test set up implementing the Parameters in the before method as well as the `TestNG XML`.

Thanks for any help!

[image: testng.xml screen shot 1]

[image: testng.xml screen shot 2]

Comment: Try including your code in a pastebin instead of including screen shots - they are very hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

Even if it is working at test level, TestNG is doing what it supposed to do (calling methods).
So, the problem is located in your `LoginDataSheet#getTableArray(...)` which is throwing an IOException depending on how you run your test.